# How to add a Vue component to the file app.js in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I was watching a tutorial that uses laravel and vue and on the tutorial he add a vue component in the components folder and then register that component in `app.js` file using this code

```
Vue.component('articles',require('./components/articles.vue');
```

And it works fine and in my case when I use this code it says `require is not defined`.
In the `app.js` file theres already an example component registered using this code

```
Vue.component('example-component',__webpack_require__(37));
```

My question is how does the number `37` define the `ExampleComponent.vue` file? And how can I get the number of the file i want to include? And I don't have the webpack CLI
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like i have been using the wrong app.js file which was in the public directory i should be adding these codes to the app.js which sits in the components directory

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
import YourComponent from 'path';
new Vue({

  components: {
   "your-component": YourComponent

});
```